# Configuration at DNS provider end while adding custom domain purchased from hostinger to web application hosted on heroku

Tags: heroku, dns, hosting, cname

I want my custom domain to point to my webapplication hosted on heroku.  I need help about how to do configuration on hostinger side. Steps that i have already performed.

1. Purchased a domain name from hostinger.
2. On heroku app, i have run following command

```
$ heroku domains:add samplecustomdomain.com
$ heroku domains:add www.samplecustomdomain.com
$ heroku domains

This command gives output something like -

Domain Name                   DNS Record Type    DNS Target                                              
samplecustomdomain.com        ALIAS or ANAME     xyz1.herokudns.com     
www.samplecustomdomain.com    CNAME              xyz2.herokudns.com
```

3. On Hostinger side, after clicking on manage samplecustomdomain.com , i get two tabs for setting.

   a) **Domain management** - It has options like **update nameservers, create child nameservers**

   b) **DNS Zone** - It has options to add like **A (Host) , CNAME(alias), MX (Mail Exchanger) , TXT (Text) ,  AAAA (IPv6 Address Record) ,  NS (Nameserver) , SRV  , CAA***

I think i have to modify **CNAME(alias)** to register my application. Under  CNAME(alias), i have to supply values of following fields

```
Host       -
Points to  -
TTL        -
```

Kindly help what values need to be supplied for above field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your DNS Zone, add a ALIAS/ANAME/CNAME record (if Hostinger has ALIAS or AName, use that, if not you can use CNAME instead):

```
Host       samplecustomdomain.com
Points to  xyz1.herokudns.com
TTL        3600 (or use the default if there's any)
```

Then add a CNAME record:

```
Host       www.samplecustomdomain.com
Points to  xyz2.herokudns.com
TTL        3600 (or use the default if there's any)
```

If you already have records for the above records, you'll need to delete or edit the existing records to reflect as above.

Comment: while adding a A record,  "Points to  xyz1.herokudns.com" was not getting accepted with the error that it should be an ip address. However, the CNAME record accepted the provided values and its working now. After accepting the values, the Host value auto changed to www. It was like Host - www , Points to - xyz2.herokudns.com, TTL- (default).
Thanks for your help.

Comment: @himanshu My bad. The root domain needs to be ALIAS/ANAME/CNAME. I've updated the answer. Most commonly it's an A record :)

Comment: @himanshu Hi, could you provide an example for your solution? For example, on Hostinger, when adding a DNS record there are 4 input fields: "Type", "Name", "Target" and "TTL".   Would it be- Type:CNAME, Name:www.samplecustomdomain.com, Target:xyz2.herokudns.com, TTL:3600? Thanks!